# Chutzpah Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm trying to run jasmine tests on my knockout viewmodels, written in typescript via chutzpah but this doesn't seem possible due to the following error:

```
Chutzpah Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'
```

This error gets thrown whenever I access a knockout observable and can be recreated via the following simple example.

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

module Example {
    export class KnockoutClass {
        public anObservable = ko.observable<string>();

        public aComputed = ko.computed<boolean>(() => {
            return this.anObservable().length() > 5;
        });
    }
}

describe("This", () => {
    it(" will throw an error", () => {        

        var temp: Example.KnockoutClass = new Example.KnockoutClass();

    });
});
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here or is chutzpah not compatible with the knockout/typescript combination?

**UPDATE**

So I've managed to get chutzpah to run my tests by doing the following:

1. Remove the 'Jasmine Test Framework' NuGet package from my project and replace it with the 'jasmine.js' NuGet package instead.
2. Add a jasmine specrunner.html file to my tests directory that references my tests and their dependencies
3. In Tools->Options->Chutzpah->Unit Test Explorer set Testing Mode to HTML
4. Run tests from the Test Explorer window

This gets my tests running successfully but I still get the same exception when I try to run by right click->'Run JS Tests' and I can't debug tests either.

The issue seems to be that none of my references are resolved (the filter method is defined within jquery) so maybe I need to use require.js or some other module loader to resolve my dependencies?

Comment: reference jquery in your test xml and try

Comment: @Baz1nga I don't follow, what test xml?

Comment: If you are still having this problem please file an issue on Chutzpah.codeplex.com and attach a zipped repro of your issue.

Comment: Thanks this is fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by upgrading to the latest version of Chutzpah.